# Saving UTF-8 characters in MySQL db

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, html-entities

How can I save UTF-8 character(Malayalam language) to the MySQL database as HTML entity using PHP. I have tried some of the php functions to do the same still I am not able to make it. So it will be helpful if someone point me in the right direction.

Here is what I've done:

- Set the field collation to 'utf-8_general_ci'.
- Set the content-type to utf-8 in the page header.
- Used php function htmlentities() and
  htmlspecialchars().

Answer (score 2):

Create/change your table collation = utf-8, set names to utf-8 http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en//charset-connection.html

also use utf-8 internally on your server and declare your website utf-8 with the appropriate tags

Answer (score 0):

At last I got the solution myself :)

There is a php function to convert the characters to HTML entity.

```
mb_convert_encoding("$SPECIAL_CHAR",'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');
```

Comment: Then your internal encoding is not utf-8, read my answer above :-)